# Weights of neural network not changing

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I'm working on a tensorflow project, in which I have a neural network in a reinforcement learning system, used to predict the Q values. I have  50 inputs and 10 outputs. Some of the inputs are in the range 30-70, and the rest are between 0-1, so I normalize only the first group, using this formula:

> x_new = (x - x_min)/(x_max - x_min)

Although I know the mathematical base of neural networks, I do not have experience applying them in real cases, so I do not really know if the hyperparameters I am using are correctly chosen. The ones I have currently are:

- 2 hidden layers with 10 and 20 neurons each
- Learning rate of 0.5
- Batch size of 10 (I have tried with different values until 256 obtaining the same result)

The problem I'm not able to solve is that the weights of this neural network only change in the first two or three iterations, and stay fixed afterwards.

What I had read in other posts is that the algorithm is finding a local optima, and that the normalization of the inputs is a good idea to solve it. However, after normalizing the inputs, I am still in the same state. So, my question is if anyone knows where the problem may be, and if there is any other technique (like normalization) that I should add to my pipeline.

I haven't added any line of code in the question, because I think my problem is rather conceptual. However, in case more details were needed, I would insert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some pointers you can check:

1. 50 input data points with 10 classes?... The data is too small for the netowrk to learn anything at all if this is the case
2. Which activation function are you using. Try ReLU instead of sigmoid or tanh:
   [activation functions](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-1/#actfun)
3. How deep is your network? maybe all your graident is either vanishing or exploding:
   [vanishing or exploding gradients](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap5.html)
4. check if your training data overfits. if not your network is not learning anything

Comment: I am already using ReLU. I have tried different configurations of hidden layers, and with all of them I get the same result. Regarding the points 1 and 4, it doesn´t overfit, so I guess you are right when you say it is not learning. In case this problem is caused by the fact that my data is too small, which one would be a more realistic number of classes? I could reduce them, but I can not increase the data, since the variables are fixed. I have also tried with two classes, and it doesn´t seem to improve.

Comment: First of all, why not try other simpler models which require less data? Have you already tried them. in many cases, simple classifiers like SVM, naive Bayes would work if your data is small

Also, even if you reduce the number of classes to 2, it wont help as the data is very less
neural networks perform very well in most cases but  requires huge amount of data to train.
I would suggest:
1. try data augmentation
2. Try overfitting your training data
3. Use different learning rates ans use regularization since your data is small
4. make your network shallow- 2 layer network